# Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'bootstrap3.templatetags.bootstrap3': cannot import name 'flatatt'

Tags: django, django-bootstrap3

I don't know what happened but all of the sudden i am getting this error:

Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'bootstrap3.templatetags.bootstrap3': cannot import name 'flatatt'

any ideas?

Comment: did you upgraded django version?

Comment: Yes, i am using 1.11.3 right now

Comment: its changed in 1.11, you need to change a settings in bootstrap core file or you need to upgrade the bootstrap

Comment: can you tell me what to change? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look for the file which gives the error

and change the line having `flatatt` in the import to the given line

```
from django.forms.utils import flatatt
```

Comment: this line can be found in bootstrap/components.py and utils.py. It's strange that when I look for the line "from django.forms.widgets import flatatt" through pycharm search it doesn't find it. thanks.

Comment: Just upgrade/downgrade to pip install Django==1.10 worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can get the [latest version of django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/releases) . That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had also such problem and I found the way like this!

1-step) in components.py file in  venv\Lib\site-packages\bootstrap3
it was written :

`from django.forms.widgets import flatatt`

you should change it to 
`from django.forms.utils import flatatt`

2-step)in utils.py file in folder venv\Lib\site-packages\bootstrap3 
it was written :

`from django.forms.widgets import flatatt`

you should change it to :

`from django.forms.utils import flatatt`